# SQL Query to Find the Customer whos First order was on Sunday

Tags: sql

I have 2 data tables.

Table 1: DK_Table

```
DK_ID   DK_Name Dk_location Cust_Id Amount  Event   Time _stamp
1   A   KOR01   111123  752 Order_Placed    8-14-21 21:05
3   C   WHF01   111123  688 Order_Placed    8-15-21 22:20
1   A   KOR01   111123  752 Order_Accepted  8-14-21 21:05
1   A   KOR01   111123  752 Order_Prepared  8-14-21 21:09
1   A   KOR01   111123  752 Order_Picked    8-14-21 21:25
```

Table 2: Delivery_Agent_Table

```
DEX_Id  Cust_Id DK_Id   Event   Time Stamp
AAEE01  111123  1   Delivery_Assigned   8-14-21 21:07
AAEE01  111123  1   Arrived_DK Location 8-14-21 21:20
AAEE01  111123  1   Arrived_Destination 8-14-21 21:40
```

From the above 2 tables interviewer asked me to write queries for below questions.

Question: Write a SQL query to count of users who ordered food for the first time on Sunday for each DK

Comment: which database system? Please show us your attempt fro this problem. What is "DK"? Which table represent food orders and which users?

Comment: Is `8-14-21 21:05` supposed to be a timestamp? Column data type?

Comment: @RadimBača DK_Table is order table and all the orders are FOOD only. From this i want to write a query to get the below details: For each DK_NAME customer (Cust_Id) who ordered for the first time on Sunday

Comment: The question is not clear.  Is the first order for the customer in that DK?  Or is it the first order for the customer overall?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, your sample data isn't really sufficient to fully show the solution, but working with what we have:

```
declare @DK_Table table(
    DK_ID int,
    DK_Name varchar(1),
    Dk_location varchar(5),
    Cust_Id int,
    Amount int,
    [Event] varchar(15),
    [Time _stamp] datetime
)

insert into @DK_Table values
(1,'A','KOR01',111123,752,'Order_Placed',  '2021-08-14 21:05:00.000'),
(3,'C','WHF01',111123,688,'Order_Placed',  '2021-08-15 22:20:00.000'),
(1,'A','KOR01',111123,752,'Order_Accepted','2021-08-14 21:05:00.000'),
(1,'A','KOR01',111123,752,'Order_Prepared','2021-08-14 21:09:00.000'),
(1,'A','KOR01',111123,752,'Order_Picked',  '2021-08-14 21:25:00.000')

select count(distinct Cust_Id)
from
(
    select 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_Id ORDER BY [Time _stamp]) as OrderNumber
    from @DK_Table
    where [Event] = 'Order_Placed'
    and datepart(weekday,[Time _stamp]) = 1 --Presuming your DATEFIRST is set to the default, so Sunday is 1
) a
where a.OrderNumber = 1
```

The `Delivery_Agent_Table` doesn't seem relevant to the question you are trying to answer, assuming that the definition of "a user who ordered food" is a record in the `DK_Table` with an `Event` of `Order_Placed`.

The `distinct` in the select clause should not be strictly necessary, as each `Cust_Id` should only have one first order, but I put it there just as a safety net in case the real data is somehow different.